# Instalar Pattern en Genexus

Tags: genexus

Estoy queriendo instalar el pattern WorkWithPlus for Web en mi Genexus 17 pero no se como alguien me podría ayudar por favor

Answer (score 1):

Para instalar WorkWithPlus for Web, debes descargar el setup desde [developer.workwithplus.com.](https://developer.workwithplus.com)

Una vez que lo descargas, lo debes instalar seleccionando la ruta de tu instalación de GeneXus, y luego podrás solicitar tu licencia.

Si ya la has adquirido podrás solicitarla con el usuario enviado durante la compra. Si no tienes licencia, puedes usar la clave trial que es completamente gratuita. En [workwithplus.com/trial](https://workwithplus.com/trial) tienes todo el detalle de cómo solicitarla.

En [WorkWithPlus Academy](https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?3419,Toc%3AWorkWithPlus%20Academy,) tienes varios cursos para aprovechar al máximo tu licencia trial. Si además deseas una demo personalizada puedes solicitarla en [workwithplus.com/requestdemo](https://workwithplus.com/requestdemo).